# Is this the correct form of the adjective?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs

Francis Lalanne's song "On se retrouvera" starts with the following words:

```
Promets-moi si tu me survis
D’être plus fort que jamais
```

I've always assumed that a feminine form is necessary in such cases: plus forte. So are these lyrics grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La chanson a été écrite pour le film fantastique "Le Passage", où un père se bat pour sauver son fils qui est dans le coma. Dans ce contexte, les paroles s'adressent effectivement à un garçon.

Answer (score 2):

Tout dépend du contexte, il faudrait peut-être préciser le genre des personnes dont il s'agit dans la chanson ; est-ce adressé à un homme (chanson sur l'amitié ou quelque chose comme ça) ? est-ce  adressé à une femme (chanson d'amour habituelle) ? S'il n'y a aucune indication solide du genre de la personne on doit supposer qu'il s'agit d'une personne du genre masculin ; autrement il y a une erreur d'impression ou ce qui est plus improbable, une erreur dans les paroles. Il semble que vous n'ayez pas écouté la chanson ; vous devriez pouvoir différencier « fort » de « forte », ce sont des mots assez différents, un t est prononcé dans « forte » alors qu'il ne l'est pas dans « fort ».

Comment: La chanson a été écrite pour le film fantastique "Le Passage", où un père se bat pour sauver son fils qui est dans le coma. Dans ce contexte, les paroles s'adressent effectivement à un garçon.

Comment: @user168676 I have heard the song and read the lyrics, and I know how the two words are pronounced, that is why I asked this question. To me, he quite clearly pronounces [fɔʁ], not [fɔʁt].

Comment: @Greg this is actually the correct answer because it explains why it should be masculine. Could you, please, make your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?